# Docker error: 'useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd'

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a pipeline in Azure DevOps to run the Docker cirrus/flutter image. An error occurs when Azure tries to initialize the container (in the useradd command). Below is the final part of the execution log with the error:

```
##[command]/usr/bin/docker exec  5ae52fcbeefecc0df48056df5f9d673429fe5173e7a8e3d984d889ce5223c34c sh -c "command -v bash"
/bin/bash
##[command]whoami 
vsts
##[command]id -u vsts
1001
Try create an user with UID '1001' inside the container.
##[command]/usr/bin/docker exec  5ae52fcbeefecc0df48056df5f9d673429fe5173e7a8e3d984d889ce5223c34c bash -c "grep 1001 /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d:"
##[command]/usr/bin/docker exec  5ae52fcbeefecc0df48056df5f9d673429fe5173e7a8e3d984d889ce5223c34c id -u bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
id: extra operand 'warning:'
Try 'id --help' for more information.
##[command]/usr/bin/docker exec  5ae52fcbeefecc0df48056df5f9d673429fe5173e7a8e3d984d889ce5223c34c useradd -m -u 1001 vsts_azpcontainer
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
##[error]Docker exec fail with exit code 1
##[section]Finishing: Initialize containers
```

This is my azure-pipelines.yml

```
jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  container: cirrusci/flutter:latest
  steps:
  - bash: flutter doctor
```

How can I solve this?
I thank everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Move the `container` to a `resource` section and pass the docker option `--user 0:0` as `options`.

For example:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: flutter
    image: cirrusci/flutter:latest
    options: --user 0:0

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  container: flutter
  steps:
  - bash: flutter doctor
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't lock the `passwd` file because you're not running the `useradd` command as root.  The `cirrusci/flutter` image runs as the `cirrus` user by default:

```
$ docker run -it  cirrusci/flutter id
uid=1000(cirrus) gid=999(cirrus) groups=999(cirrus),27(sudo)
```

You need to be `root` to modify `/etc/passwd`.  You can run a command as root inside an existing container by using the `-u` option to `docker exec`. Compare this:

```
$ docker exec flutter useradd testuser
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
$
```

To this:

```
$ docker exec -u root flutter useradd testuser
$
```

In this specific case, it looks as if the `cirrus` user is able to run `sudo`, so you could also accomplish the same thing like this:

```
$ docker exec flutter sudo useradd testuser
$
```

Comment: Sorry for the innocent question, but I'm still a beginner in CI: the commands in the log that I presented in the question, are executed directly by Azure, not through my yaml script. How can I apply your suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not at all familiar with Azure. I guess consider this half the answer until someone familiar with Azure pipelines can come along and address that side of the question.